# Why are 2D images sometimes modeled as pointer to pointers (T**)?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, image-processing

Some image data structure implementations use pointer to pointers (e.g. `T**`). The first pointer points to the rows/cols of the data, the second pointer points to the data element in the row/col.

What's the advantage of this data structure in comparison to a single pointer to the data (e.g. `T*`)?

I realize this is a broad question, so I would narrow the question to modern work for a C++ and a C compiler ("lowest common denominator").

Comment: Pick a language! C and C++ are **different** languages!

Comment: @Olaf they are different languages, but both have pointer to pointers and support this data structure. Tagging with both languages is fine where both languages are concerned.

Comment: @ᐅJohannesSchaub-litbᐊ Due to overloading, the question might be broader for C++. Also there might be different solutions in both languages, e.g. VLA (see comments below) which are not avail for C++ and an answer may/will differ very much.

Comment: The question ist flagged as too broad. Would it help to specify the c++ standard version in the question?

Comment: @Olaf: Overloading affects function naming, but not data structures.

Comment: @tisch To begin with, you must narrow the question down by picking one single programming language.

Comment: @tisch: No, C++ standard versions do not matter here. A `T**` is an array of arrays, and those have been standard since 1970 or so.

Comment: @MSalters: It might change semantics. Not to mention smartpointers, etc.

Comment: @MSalters: A pointer is **not** an array!

Comment: The C answer would be: don't use pointer-to-pointer, use a 2D array. The C++ answer would probably be: don't use pointer-to-pointer, use `vector<vector<T> >`.

Comment: @Olaf: Nitpick. An image isn't a 2D array either. But for practical purposes, `T** == array of arrays == image`

Comment: @MSalters: Nonsense! Try `sizeof(T **)` and `sizeof(T[dim1][dim2])` or alloc/free. Let alone the difference between new/malloc, ...

Comment: @Olaf: That is precisely why I said "Nitpick". You're technically correct but read the second sentence of the question. The distinction is understood and being excessively precise does not aid further understanding.

Comment: @MSalters: You forget the question is read by beginners, too. Many questions here arise from imprecise terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advantages of using `T**`:

- more natural syntax for element indexing (`a[i][j]` rather than `a[i * width + j]`)
- does not require multiply for indexing (multiplication is still expensive on low end CPUS, e.g. micro-controllers)
- may be a better fit for whatever third party or legacy APIs that you might be using
- works for non-rectangular images (i.e. where width of each row may not be constant)
- can make border processing easier when you have neighbourhood operations (define additional rows at start/end of image which are aliased to their reflected row indices)
- allows row alignment to be optimised for efficiency, e.g. when using SIMD (can make each row SIMD-aligned even if image width is not a convenient multiple)

Note that you can have the "best of both worlds" if you allocate images like this:

```
T* image_buffer = malloc(height * width * sizeof(T)); // allocate "flat" image
T** image = malloc(height * sizeof(T*));              // allocate row pointers
image[0] = image_buffer;                              // init row pointers
for (int i = 1; i < height; ++i)
    image[i] = image[i - 1] + width;
```

This way you get a contiguous image, `image_buffer`, which can be accessed as `image[i * width + j]`, or it can be treated as a `T**` image which can be accessed as `image[i][j]`. This can useful when you have different APIs which expect image data in different formats. It's also more efficient for `T**` images than the naïve approach of using one `malloc` per row.

Comment: On a low-end CPU/MCU, memory is also precious and `malloc` & Co are likely not available. For regular arrays, one often would just use a (near) power-of-two array-size (modern compilers will replace constant multiplication on such targets by shift/add). It is a trade-off.

Comment: 1) Why not use a true 2D array? This will also avoid an additional indirection. 2) using `var = malloc(... * sizeof(*var))` avoids having to change the type twice when editing.

Comment: @Olaf: true 2D arrays require that at least one dimension is known at compile-time, so this limits their usefulness when working with arbitrarily sized images.

Comment: Not if you use `T (*array)[dim1][dim2]`. Only drawback is you have to dereference the pointer first. Alternatively use `T (*array)[dim2]`, which is - strictly speaking not a 2D array, but behaves alike.

Comment: @PaulR " 2D arrays require that at least one dimension is known at compile-time" There was a new version of the C standard released 16 years ago... Simply use an array pointer to VLA and have it point at the dynamically allocated chunk of data. "Mangled" 2D arrays are no longer needed.

Comment: Well I was keeping my answer as "lowest common denominator" as possible - the question is tagged both [tag:c] and [tag:c++], and C++ doesn't have VLAs. Also MSVC has only just started (partially) supporting C99, so a lot of people still have to use C89 paradigms. Furthermore the OP is specifically asking about flat `T*` images versus 2D `T**` images.

Comment: I overlooked C++, asked OP to clarify this. For C, however, unless C90/K&R is stated, I refer to the standard, which clearly allows VLAs. Using an outdated, broken non-standard compiler is not something one should care about - unless OP asks for that.

Comment: I think that the syntax is not natural because pixel coordinates should be used in reverse order `[y][x]`.

Comment: @AndreyNasonov: I'm not sure what you mean - in the above example `i == row == y`, `j == col == x`. So it's "row major", which is natural for C and related languages. Did you want something different ?

Comment: @PaulR, I mean it is natural for human that the first parameter is `x` and the second one is `y` (we are speaking about images, not matrices).

Answer (score 1):

1) You can reference a point by (x,y) coordinates instead of a computing the respective index in a one dimensional array. (uchar** can be used as uchar[x][y])

2) You can simply use complete rows/columns in e.g. vector operation by passing the respective pointers of the rows/columns - that should be used - into the operation.

Comment: Neither `char *` nor `char **` are arrays!

Comment: Access order `[x][y]` is significantly less efficient than `[y][x]`. Images are accessed row-by-row so `x` coordinate should be the last. It is better wrap pixel access by a class to keep natural (x, y) order.